# Redirect restfull api codeigniter

Tags: json, api, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, rest

I want to ask how to redirect the results from the input code form post like this

how do i redirect resfull api I want after input_post () page will be redirected

```
public function loginsi_post(){
    $username = $this->post('username');
    $password = $this->post('password');
    $data = [];
    $data['username'] = $username;
    $data['password'] = $password;
    if ($this->model_app->insert('jajal', $data) > 0) {
        $this->response([
            'message' => 'data berhasil disimpan',
            'data'    => $data
        ], REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED);
    }else{
        $this->response([
            'message' => 'data gagal disimpan'
        ], REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
redirect('main/home'); ---------> is not working
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please setup your route like as below.

```
 public function index() { 
         /*Load the URL helper*/ 
         $this->load->helper('url'); 

         /*Redirect the user to some site*/ 
         redirect('http://www.example.com'); 
      }
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Note: One can not access any controller that is in other folder and script access is not allowed this way. So there must be route set in route.php then you can access the function using route path. It can be defined as below:-

Like for example:- In route.php, the route is defined as:-

```
$route['your uri']='your uri';
```

then to access controller :-

$captcha_url = "http://your_api_url/index.php/nlpgen/nlpimg/"
Now you can use CURL to access the external URL.

Comment: but I want that after I input data using restapi redirect directly to another page how to route the settings page